# Need Help ! (Minecraft Hack Client ESP)

Tags: client, minecraft

I need help by programming my Hack ESP for my minecraft hack client !
I saw this code in a Youtube tutorial but it wont work for me!

Code:

```
package net.YouNeedHimAndYouHeNeedsYou.hacks;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import net.YouNeedHimAndYouHeNeedsYou.client.Category;
import net.YouNeedHimAndYouHeNeedsYou.client.Module;
import net.YouNeedHimAndYouHeNeedsYou.client.Renderutilitis.RenderUtils;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityMob;
import net.minecraft.entity.passive.EntityAnimal;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;

public class ESP extends Module{

public static final String  = null;

public ESP() {
    super("ESP", 0xB72198, Keyboard.KEY_NONE, Category.RENDER);
}


public void onRender() {

    if(!this.isEnabled());
       return;


       *for(Object theObject : mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList) {
           if(!(theObject instanceof EntityLivingBase)) 
               continue;


           EntityLivingBase entity = (EntityLivingBase) theObject;

           if(entity instanceof EntityPlayer) {
               if(entity != mc.thePlayer)
                   player(entity);
               continue;
           }

           if(entity instanceof EntityMob) {
               mob(entity);
               continue;
           }
           if(entity instanceof EntityAnimal) {
               animal(entity);
               continue;
       }
           passive(entity);*

           super.onRender();
       }
}

public void player(EntityLivingBase entity) {
    float red = 0.5F;
    float green = 0.5F;
    float blue = 1F;

    double xPos = (entity.lastTickPosX + (entity.posX - entity.lastTickPosX) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosX;
    double yPos = (entity.lastTickPosY + (entity.posY - entity.lastTickPosY) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosY;
    double zPos = (entity.lastTickPosZ + (entity.posZ - entity.lastTickPosZ) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosZ;

    render(red, green, blue, xPos, yPos, zPos);
}
public void mob(EntityLivingBase entity) {
    float red = 1F;
    float green = 0.5F;
    float blue = 0.5F;

    double xPos = (entity.lastTickPosX + (entity.posX - entity.lastTickPosX) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosX;
    double yPos = (entity.lastTickPosY + (entity.posY - entity.lastTickPosY) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosY;
    double zPos = (entity.lastTickPosZ + (entity.posZ - entity.lastTickPosZ) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosZ;

    render(red, green, blue, xPos, yPos, zPos);

}
public void animal(EntityLivingBase entity) {
float red = 0.5F;
float green = 1F;
float blue = 0.5F;

double xPos = (entity.lastTickPosX + (entity.posX - entity.lastTickPosX) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosX;
double yPos = (entity.lastTickPosY + (entity.posY - entity.lastTickPosY) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosY;
double zPos = (entity.lastTickPosZ + (entity.posZ - entity.lastTickPosZ) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosZ;

render(red, green, blue, xPos, yPos, zPos);

}
public void passive(EntityLivingBase entity) {
    float red = 0.5F;
    float green = 1F;
    float blue = 0.5F;

    double xPos = (entity.lastTickPosX + (entity.posX - entity.lastTickPosX) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosX;
    double yPos = (entity.lastTickPosY + (entity.posY - entity.lastTickPosY) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosY;
    double zPos = (entity.lastTickPosZ + (entity.posZ - entity.lastTickPosZ) * mc.timer.renderPartialTicks) - mc.getRenderManager().renderPosZ;

    render(red, green, blue, xPos, yPos, zPos);

}

public void render(float red, float green, float blue, double x, double y, double z) {
    RenderUtils.drawTracerLine(x, y, z, red, green, blue, 0.45F, 1F);
}

}        `
```

`The text which is in * is wrong with the designation: Unreachable code`

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is full of syntax errors.

```
if(!this.isEnabled());
  return;
```

should be

```
if(!this.isEnabled()){return;}
```

And what's with the random asterisks? Remove the asterisks on:

```
*for(Object theObject : mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList) {
```

and

```
passive(entity);*
```